# magento2 how to sort order of product by price

Tags: magento2, product, collection

It my code when I sort product by price but result not show

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->setOrder('price', 'DESC');

return $collection;
```

Comment: Please try before `return $collection;` `echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();` or `echo $collection>printlogquery(true); `

Answer (score 9):

Use **addAttributeToSort()** function *for sorting product collection by* price.

So,

```
$collection->setOrder('price', 'DESC');
```

Change to

```
$collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'DESC');
```

Comment: I want to sort my custom price after page load. **@Amit**